# Run shell script by double clicking .desktop file to launch python script

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, user-interface

I have a python script named `script.py` I want to double click on `script.desktop`, and it will execute the shell file `script.sh`, which will then evecute the python file: `script.py`.

My `script.desktop` file contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=jobs
Comment=jobs
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/script.sh
Icon=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/icon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

My shell file `script.sh` thus looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"
sleep 2m
```

I eventually want it to execute a `script.py` file, upon executing it via the shell file, but itd make sense to first get it to echo `hi` first

I cant even get it to output the `hi` though in terminal when i double click `script.desktop` it just hangs with no error.

First I'd like for it to just run `.desktop` file, that runs the `.sh` file, and outputs hi, *then* ill worry about executing the python file.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: did you set `chmod +x script.py` ? then it may  run with double click and you don't need `script.sh`

Comment: @furas - yea already did that

Comment: If you have `#!/full/path/python` in `script.py` then you can try `Exec=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/script.py` or in `script.sh` use  `/full/path/script.py`.  If you don't have `#!/full/path/python` in `script.py`  then you need `python /full/path/script.py` in `script.sh`

Comment: @furas please see question, im not looking to get the python file ran right now. All i want to do is get it to output `hi` in terminal, when i double click on `.desktop` file, ultimately the goal is to get the python script to run, but `hi` is a good start

Comment: to run script (python or sh) you need two things - `chmod  +x`  and `#!/full/path/python` or `#!/bin/bash` (`shebang`) in script.

Comment: @furas - I have shebang in the shell script

Comment: it can't because you can't activate virtualenv before you run script with click.

Comment: it still doesnt run on a non-virtualenv python env though. I cannot double click `.desktop` and run `.sh` file

Comment: maybe it runs too fast and you don't see console/terminal. It close after it ends.

Comment: anyway to delay it closing?

Comment: add `read`  to bash script - and first test script in console/terminal manually.

Comment: Example please?

Comment: example: `read`

Comment: sleep 2m, works fine by manually executing `.sh` by itself. Its executing `.desktop` then it just hangs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"

read
```

Set `chmod +x script.sh` and try manually in console/terminal - you may have to add `./` at start to run it

```
./script.sh
```

**script.desktop**

In Linux Mint system adds first line with `#!` - so maybe it needs it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=jobs
Comment=jobs
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/script.sh
Icon=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/icon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Set `chmod +x script.desktop` and try click it

**script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Hello World!")

input()
```

Set `chmod +x script.py` and try manually in console/terminal

```
./script.py
```

Add to `script.sh` - better with full path

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"

/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/script.py
```

(because script.py has `shebang` and set `chmod +x` so you don't have to use `python` in  `script.sh`. You can even remove extension in file and in script)

Or use directly in `.desktop`

**script-py.desktop**

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=jobs-py
Comment=jobs-py
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/script.py
Icon=/home/user/Desktop/school_scrape/icon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Set `chmod +x script-py.desktop` and try click it

Comment: thanks, this works. Do i just add `python script.py` to `script.sh`? I'll accept shortly after. Thank you so much!

Comment: you can add `python script.py` to `script.sh` or you can use `script.py` directly in `.desktop` file.

Comment: How can i use directly in `.desktop` ?

Comment: you can use directly in `.desktop`  the same way as `script.sh` - see new text in answer.  `script.sh` and `script.py` with correct `shebang` and `chmod +x` are treated by Linux the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert the following line in script.sh: `python script.py`

Or you can make it executable by using command: `chmod +x script.py` and just write in script.sh: `./script.py`

Comment: I cant even echo `hi` nevermind running the python script

Comment: Here are useful references: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows